# Make 3 passes for a target

Tags: makefile

I'll explain myself, here is my scenario:

- Compile my target
- Do a first optimization based on the first compilation
- Do a second optimization based on the first optimization
- Do a third optimization based on the second optimization

So far I tried the following:

```
.SUFFIXES:
.SECONDARY:

OBJECTS := $(addsuffix .obj,$(SOURCES))
override OBJECTS := $(OBJECTS:$(SRC)/%.obj=$(OBJ)/%.obj)

OC1 := $(patsubst %.obj, %.oc1, $(filter %c.obj,$(OBJECTS)))
O1 := $(L166_CMD:%.lnp=%.o1)

all: $(TARGET) $(O1)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    @echo Linking $(TARGET)...

$(OBJ)/%.c.obj: $(SRC)/%.c
    @echo Compiling $(<F) ...

# c.oc1 is a intermediate file
%.c.oc1: %.c.obj
    @echo 1 - Optimize $<...
    @touch $@

$(O1): $(OC1)
    @touch $@
    echo Linking O1
```

Result is, I modify a C file, the target will regenerate only the modified C file but the `O1` pass will optimize all C files again like it was not done before (but it was).

How can I modify this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is your last target, `$(O1): $(OC1)`. That is each `O1` depends on **every** `OC1`.

What is the actual value of `$(O1)`? Is it supposed to be a list or a single target?

I would try to replace this rule by a pattern (if it possible).

Comment: $(O1) is a single target in my case. So what should I change?

Comment: @Arnaud, hmm, I have no idea. Could you post (i.e. to pastebin.com) an output of running `make` that shows the original issue?